# Tidy HTML output with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tidy, htmlcleaner

I have a large chunk of HTML. In order for it to fit a certain container, I crop the HTML (not just the text) at, let’s say, 200 characters. Obviously, some of the tags will remain unclosed in this case. Is there a way, except writing the cleaner myself, to clean such cropped snippet without the server being involved?

Online services with public APIs that I can use from JavaScript are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [cutter.js](http://tcorral.github.com/Cutter.js/) library. It's pretty new, so I haven't heard much about it, but it seems like what you're looking for as far as cropping goes.

Check out my fiddle, testing it out: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/jwL8v/

```
var oElement = document.getElementById("test");
Cutter.run(oElement, oElement, 100);

$("#gc").click(function(){
    /* This will count words by spaces in the text */
    var tt = $("#test").text().split(" ");
    if (typeof(console) == 'object'){    
        console.log(tt);
    }
    alert("wordcount: "+tt.length);
     
});
```

Comment: cutter.js looks promising. Thanks for the link. Though, I have tried to play with your fiddle and I found nWords param (100 in your example) absolutely unreliable. When I set it to 1 I get the whole text back. When I set it to 10, I get the header only. 57 gives me much more text than 60 and so on. Probably I need to play more with it but it is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with an elementary word-counter, and the numbers __are__ wonky. Like I said this is a new plugin, so it might take a couple of updates for it to be perfect.

Comment: Meant to mention, cutter is on github, so you can fork it modify the code and contribute to the project if you wish. Community is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Closure library has an HTML Pretty Printer module. You should be able to fork off it:

*[Closure Library](https://github.com/google/closure-library)*

Also, if you are using jQuery, try http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/html-beautifier-jquery-plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the links. But I don't really need a beautyfier. HTML can be as ugly as it gets unless it is cropped and all the cropped tags are closed.

Comment: The second link seems to be broken (times out): *"504 ERROR. The request could not be satisfied."*